# Update title attribute on hover with clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I am using [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) in order to copy some citations from a table. The basic HTML-markup is as follows:

```
<div id="citation" style="position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px;">TEXT</div>

<button type="button" class="btn clipboard-btn ion-clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#citation"></button>
```

Now I am trying to display a title/text on mouse-over explaining what the user can do when clicking on the button (we only use an icon there).

I tried using a `title="something"` on the button but clipboard.js overwrites that and leaves it behind empty. Also manually setting `data-original-title="something"` doesn't do the trick.

What am I missing? How can I (preferably natively) achieve a mouseover-title on my button?

Comment: Can you use `input` instead of `button`?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after executing  **`clipboard.js`**, find your button and set its title programmatically

```
$('Button').attr('title', 'something');
```

Comment: Buttons do not have a `title` attribute. Might work in some browsers, but it's not spec. https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button

Comment: @David take it easy, all modern browsers support it, and its the only way to getting ride of overwrite (pointed in question)

Comment: This might not be spec and won't be acessible in older browsers but it does the job for me – hope that choice doesn't offend anyone :)